# Why does MySQL return different result when query column with or without order by?

Tags: mysql

I have table

```
CREATE TABLE `record_temp_var` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `p_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `var_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    `var_value` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY idx_var_name(`var_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has a bunch of records, but I found a strange thing with executing these two sqls.

```
SELECT id FROM `record_temp_var` order by id limit 10;
```

The first row return with `order by id` is the really first record of this table.

```
SELECT id FROM `record_temp_var` limit 10;
```

But without `order by id`, the first row return is not the first record in the table.

I have researched MySQL for quite a long time. I believe that MySQL may use a different index.

- Primary Key
- idx_var_name

But why I select id, MySQL use the `idx_var_name` index?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208452/what-does-mysql-actually-use-to-decide-which-index-should-be-used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your second `LIMIT` query which does *not* have an `ORDER BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT id FROM record_temp_var LIMIT 10;
```

it is not really a relevant point how MySQL chooses 10 records from the table.  Rather, you the only thing which you should be assuming in this case is that MySQL is free to choose *any* 10 records it wants, since you did not provide instructions to the contrary.

In general, when using `LIMIT` you should *always* include an `ORDER BY` clause to make the query have sense.